# Create spot instance by API with non-default VPC in ruby API

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

We use Ruby AWS-SDK version 2 for creating spot request that creates instance in default VPC.
We Like to create spot request with non-default VPC. 
How can we pass non-default VPC in create spot request?

```
{
          :spot_price => spot_price,
          :type => 'one-time',
          :instance_count => 1,
          :launch_group => role,
          :launch_specification => {
              :image_id => image_id,
              :instance_type => instance_type,
              placement: {
                  availability_zone: zone
              },
              :security_groups => [security_group],
              block_device_mappings: [{
                    device_name: "/dev/sda1",
                    ebs: {
                        delete_on_termination: true
                    }
                }
              ]
          }
      }
```

where I can pass VPC ID or which attribute I need to add to create spot request in different VPC.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#request_spot_instances-instance_method